# Strange problem with [tableView reloadData]

Tags: iphone, uitableview, invalidation, reloaddata

Let have two mutable arrays, and let's have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray *A = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *B = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // fill up A
    // B remains empty
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ...
    if (...)
    {
        // fill up the cell with datas of an object from A
    }
    else
    {
        // fill up the cell with datas of an object from B
    }
    //...
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (...)
    {
        // remove an object from A and put it in B
    }
    else
    {
        // remove an object from B and put in A
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

If [tableView reloadData] is commented out (// [tableView reloadData]), than after the "click" the table will not be invalidated, as expected. And if the present cell scrolled off and scrolled in the screen again, "cellForRowAtIndexPath" is called and the cell "drawed" right according to which array from should its content be gained.
But if [tableView reloadData] is active, while "cellForRowAtIndexPath" is not called at all (!) and the cell is deleted from the screen!

reaction: WHUT?

Can help me anybody how to invalidate the tableview on the fly (not by scrolling the cell off and in :))!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would do the updating of the affected cells in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method rather than calling reloadData there.

Comment: Did you use different cell identifiers?

Comment: Have you tried using `delete/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`? So long as your arrays match the changes, this should provide an immediate change to your tableView without the need to call `reloadData`.

Comment: @Terente: same cell identifier is used.

@onnoweb: the sort of the cells should be changed too, when an object goes from A to B and vica versa.

@slev: no, good idea. I'll try at monday :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault.. It's a very good experience, to me about this thing.
The method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [A count] + [B count];
}
```

only contained *[A count]* and *[B count]* not.. Actually with reloadData it wors propery. Anyhow it works due scroll-up - scroll-down while the *numberOfRowsInSection* is not queryed again.

Thank you all for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [UITableView method -deleteRowsAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a)... to perform the delete you're trying to achieve. Apple may not approve this UI paradigm though, as it violates the HIG.

Consider using the editing property, along with [-commitEditingStyle... of the UITableViewDatasource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for doing delete. Users will already be familiar with this usage of the table view, and it isn't at risk of being rejected by Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but may I don't understand it. I don't want to delete any row. I'd like to put an object from an array to the other array, when the user taps on it. And both array should be visible in the tableview. Just imagine, as B array would contain the selected objects with some sort applied on them. The A array contains the unselected objects. Simple checkboxes are not enough, while there can not be sorting method. It was just an example to describe the problem, the real task is a little bit more complex.

Comment: You might want to reconsider your approach to the problem. Trying to use two arrays to track objects merged into a single table, without sections, is going to be rather painful. Perhaps you could use the table with selections, sorting, whatever else you need, on a single array, and when the user is done (either by pressing a button or closing the application) iterate over the array and build your two data representations at that point. Otherwise, you're going to be fighting with UITableView quite a bit.